# I can't clear external interrupts in Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, interrupt, interrupt-handling, atmega32

I'm working on a project using an arduino uno board, I'm using an External interrupt tied to a switch 
I wanted this switch to work only if i sent an activation order to the board 
The Problem is that, if the switch is pressed before i send the command, i get a pressed state once i send the command, even the switch is not pressed, which mean the external interrupt save the state before i and retrieve it once i enable it
here is a snippet of the code

```
volatile boolean  EX_INT = 0, activate = 0;
const byte interruptBin = 3;
const byte ACTIVATE = 0x55;
unsigned char frame[] = {0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(interruptBin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if(activate == 1){
    //EIMSK =0;  EIFR = 0; I tried to clear the last interrupt but with no effect
    activate = 0; EX_INT = 0;
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptBin),buttonPressed,RISING);  
    while(EX_INT != 1);
    EX_INT = 0; 
    Serial.write((uint8_t*)frame, sizeof(frame)); 
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptBin)); 
  }
}

void serialEvent(){
  while (Serial.available()){
    value = Serial.read();
    if(value == ACTIVATE)
      activate = 1;
  }
}

void buttonPressed()      
{  
  EX_INT = 1;        
}
```

Comment: please add your setup(). what is interruptBin? what is frame? what is ACTIVATE?

Comment: @Piglet I added them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for `activate` in your interrupt handler:

```
void buttonPressed()      
{
  if(activate) {  
    EX_INT = 1;   
  }     
}
```